# Convert LocalDateTime to Instant requires a ZoneOffset. Why?

Tags: java, java-time

I need to convert a `LocalDateTime` object to a new `Instant` object.

I've realized `LocalDateTime` has an `toInstant` method, but it's requesting me an `ZoneOffset`.

I don't quite figure out how to use it, or what does `ZoneOffset` meant for.

Comment: Take a look at [ZoneOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) state: The epoch-seconds are measured from the standard Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00**Z**. That **Z** stands for *Zulu timezone. The important thing is you need a timezone so Java can correctly calculate the instant from the given time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't convert a `LocalDateTime` directly to an `Instant` because a `LocalDateTime` can represent many instants. It does not represent one particular instant in time.

Here is a `LocalDateTime`:

```
23/10/2018 09:30:00
```

Can you figure out which instant of time exactly does the above refer to just by looking at it? No. Because that time in the UK is a different instant from that time in China.

To figure out what instant that time refers to, you also need to know how many hours is it offset from UTC, and that, is what `ZoneOffset` basically represents.

For example, for an offset of 8 hours, you would write this:

```
localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(8))
```

Or, if you know you always want the zone offset in the current time zone for that local date time, you can replace `ZoneOffset.ofHours(8)` with:

```
ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(localDateTime)
```

You should think about what offset you want to use before converting it to an instant.

Comment: Good explanation. Could you perhaps add a programmatic way to determine the local system's offset?

Comment: I'm on a server. How could I get current server `ZoneOffset`?

Comment: Great answer! I know the question was about **why** you have to use a ZoneOffset, but since you do, here is a simple way to do it: `localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()`

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2018, Month.OCTOBER, 10, 31, 56);
Instant instant = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome")).toInstant();
System.out.println(instant);
```

Comment: While it doesn’t really answer the “why” in the title, it clearly shows the correct way to solve the problem (one would have to substitute the correct time zone, of course).